# Large amounts of images in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I am currently developing an `iOS` App for a photographer. The main attraction of the App is going to be a gallery of their work, so about 300MB of Images.

My plan until now was to include lower resolution versions of the Images on the App itself and have the full resolution Images pulled from a `FirebaseDatabase` to replace the low-res versions.

Now I am doubting myself though, since pulling 300MB worth of Images from `Firebase` for every user seems like it would get rather costly. Would it be a better bet for me to just accept the bigger download and include all of the Images in the App? Considering that would also save the users time and give them a smoother experience it seems like the better option. But I am not sure if there are issues with this that I am not aware of.

How do people usually deal with this sort of a thing?

Comment: You can try with cloudinary which provides different options to pull and push images in different resolutions etc

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database is not well suited to storing large amounts of binary data.  You should be using an object storage solution such as Cloud Storage instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there a Cloud Storage service you could recommend? I am currently looking into every option, but it is hard to make informed decisions on something I do not understand too well. I'm also still considering just putting all the Images into the assets in high resolution and skipping external storage completely.

Comment: (Google) Cloud Storage is the name of the service.